# How does a PyFlink job call external jar?

Tags: apache-flink, pyflink

I want to call my Java interfaces in a jar file in a PyFlink job. No solutions are found in the offical document.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like support for this was not included in Flink 1.9, but is ongoing work. See [FLIP-58](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLINK/FLIP-58%3A+Flink+Python+User-Defined+Stateless+Function+for+Table). [FLIP-78](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLINK/FLIP-78%3A+Flink+Python+UDF+Environment+and+Dependency+Management) and [FLIP-88](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLINK/FLIP-88%3A+PyFlink+User-Defined+Function+Resource+Management) may also be of interest. Note that most of these improvements will be included in the upcoming Flink 1.10 release.

Comment: Yes, it is not mentioned in the doc. I have tried to call Java interface in jar file successfully with two modules "pyflink.java_gateway" and "py4j.java_gateway".  But there might be some problems hidden. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

You can use python table api to register java user-defined function if it satisfies your need. The signature of method is register_java_function in table_environment